# Classes from different packages with identical names

Tags: java, package

I have to deal with both HTML and XML data. It's not really something that'd break my neck, but there are name ambiguities between JDOM and JSoup (for example, the Document and Element classes) and writing the full qualified names over and over again (which would be the way to go according to the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)) simply means a lot of writing. Do you have any idea how to avoid the full qualified names in this case without moving the JDomClass and JSoupClass classes to their own files?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Imports {
  // ...
}

class JDomClass {
  JDomClass() throws org.jdom2.JDOMException, IOException {
    org.jdom2.Document doc =
        ew org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder().build("http://www.example.com/");
    // ...
  }
}

class JSoupClass {
  JSoupClass() throws IOException {
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc =
        org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no other way. Fully qualified names are your solution if you're using both classes in the same compilation unit.

Comment: But defining several top-level classes in the same file is an extremely bad practice, which you should never use. It's so much easier to find the file given a class name, and vice-versa, when only one class is in one file.

Comment: You're probably right about the extremely bad practice, but it is handy sometimes, so I think it really depends. But since it isn't possible anyway... :-)